# How do I cast an object without re-assigning it to another variable in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, casting, type-conversion

I have the following code (`PointLine` and `CalculatedLine` both inherit `Line`):

```
For Each line As Lines.Line In lines

    ''Since both Point and Calculated lines are stored in the same list in the XML files,
    ''we need to force them back to their original type before using them
    Select Case line.GetType()

    Case GetType(Lines.PointLine)
        line = DirectCast(line, Lines.PointLine)
        line.init()''ERROR:'init' is not a member of 'PerformanceValidation.EngineValidation.Limits.Components.Lines.Line'

        myLimitSeries.Add(line.series)

    Case GetType(Lines.CalculatedLine)
        line = DirectCast(line, Lines.CalculatedLine)
        line.init(dataTable)''ERROR:'init' is not a member of 'PerformanceValidation.EngineValidation.Limits.Components.Lines.Line'
        myLimitSeries.Add(line.series)
    End Select
Next
```

The editor complains about `line` not being of type `PointLine`/`CalculatedLine` when i call `line.init()`.

It's important that the original object be casted to either PointLine or CalculatedLine because I "initialize" them to contain calculated information that will be used later on. So basically, I don't want to create a new variable of type PointLine or CalculatedLine to act as a container for the casted Line.

I tried creating a new line of the appropriate type (exactly as I said I didn't want to above) and deleting the original line and adding the new one to the list but of course, it complains about the underlying list being modified.

Is there a way I can treat a `Line` as either a `PointLine` or `CalculatedLine` temporarily without affecting the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new instance but you need to have a second variable of the right type for the reference. I don't understand when you say "delete", when you cast, you don't delete the instance since both variable are pointing at the same instance.

```
For Each line As Lines.Line In lines

    Select Case line.GetType()

    Case GetType(Lines.PointLine)
        Dim linePoint As Lines.PointLine = DirectCast(line, Lines.PointLine)

        linePoint.init()
        myLimitSeries.Add(line.series)

    Case GetType(Lines.CalculatedLine)
        Dim lineCalculated As Lines.CalculatedLine = DirectCast(line, Lines.CalculatedLine)

        lineCalculated.init(dataTable)
        myLimitSeries.Add(line.series)
    End Select
Next
```

No new instance are created here.

If you only call one function, you could always do.

```
For Each line As Lines.Line In lines

    Select Case line.GetType()

    Case GetType(Lines.PointLine)
        DirectCast(line, Lines.PointLine).init()
        myLimitSeries.Add(line.series)

    Case GetType(Lines.CalculatedLine)
        DirectCast(line, Lines.CalculatedLine).init(dataTable)
        myLimitSeries.Add(line.series)
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Yup that did it. Very clean, very elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-type an item in a collection, because the type is set for the whole collection (in your example it's end of line 1).

I'd take a decision, whether the source data are in correct/required format or not. If you're not happy with the source format, I'd fix it there. If you need the source as is, I'd treat the lines in a layer above, but it would certainly require another collections.
Either you could convert one type of lines to another and put them into one collection or you could have one collection with some IDs and type, and two other collections for each type (you can probably use the source collections then).

Comment: I see. It's not what I had hoped, but i made a new collection and populated it with the initialized lines, then replaced the original collection altogether. Thanks for the help!